# httpd does not open index.php in folder, mounted like tmpfs

Tags: apache, tmpfs

I have a question:
I mount folder `/var/www/html/testram`

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=5m,mode=0755 tmpfs /var/www/html/testram
```

And put file index.php with some text.
When I open site from web browser I don't see any text. 
What I have:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root    root     60 May 25 17:42 testram  
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 root    root 132723 May 25 17:18 index.php
```

In logs i have errors:

PHP Warning:

```
Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/testram/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

I take an experiment and create just folder

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root     22 May 25 17:25 testfolder
```

and create file

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 132723 May 25 17:12 index.php
```

with the same text.

And when I open this index.php from web browser I see text.

Why I don't see any text from index.php mounted in tmpfs.

Thank you

`chown apache.apache -R testram` does any effect

Comment: i find this topic [link](http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks) and try use `Options FollowSymLinks` in conf of httpd. but any effect I dont get

Comment: maybe you need to know, I try do all of this in Amazon ec2 server

Answer (score 0):

You should have symlinks enabled in your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```